# Improperly formatted json?

Tags: python, json, parsing

First, I am new to Python and working with JSON.
I am trying to extract just one value from an API request response, and I am having a difficult time parsing out the data I need.
I have done a lot of searching on how to do this, but most all the examples use a string or file that is formatted is much more basic than what I am getting.
I understand the key - value pair concept but I am unsure how to reference the key-value I want. I think it has something to do with the response having multiple objects having the same kay names. Or maybe the first line "Bookmark" is making things goofy.
The value I want is for the model name in the response example below.
That's all I need from this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
{
  "Bookmark": "<B><P><p>SerNum</p><p>Item</p></P><D><f>false</f><f>false</f></D><F><v>1101666</v><v>ADDMASTER IJ7102-23E</v></F><L><v>123456</v><v>Model Name</v></L></B>",
  "Items": [
    [
      {
        "Name": "SerNum",
        "Value": "123456"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Item",
        "Value": "Model Name"
      },
      {
        "Name": "_ItemId",
        "Value": "PBT=[unit] unt.DT=[2021-07-28 08:20:33.513] unt.ID=[eae2621d-3e9f-4515-9763-55e67f65fae6]"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "Message": "Success",
  "MessageCode": 0
}
```

Comment: You want the string `"Model Name"`? Because it's associated to `"Name": "Item"`? Also, is the `Items` element deliberately an array that itself contains a single array?

Comment: I would pass your `obj.Bookmark` into a string and pass it through [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to get the "Model Name" -- Assuming you're trying to extract "ADDMASTER IJ7102-23E"

Comment: There are at least two "Model Name" strings in that sample data.  One in the Bookmark string, and one in the Item list.  Which one are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, load the JSON into a python dict:

```py
import json

x = '''{
  "Bookmark": "<B><P><p>SerNum</p><p>Item</p></P><D><f>false</f><f>false</f></D><F><v>1101666</v><v>ADDMASTER IJ7102-23E</v></F><L><v>123456</v><v>Model Name</v></L></B>",
  "Items": [
    [
      {
        "Name": "SerNum",
        "Value": "123456"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Item",
        "Value": "Model Name"
      },
      {
        "Name": "_ItemId",
        "Value": "PBT=[unit] unt.DT=[2021-07-28 08:20:33.513] unt.ID=[eae2621d-3e9f-4515-9763-55e67f65fae6]"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "Message": "Success",
  "MessageCode": 0
}'''

# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)

# The result is a Python dictionary.
```

Now if you want the value 'Model Name', you would do:

```py
print(y['Items'][0][1]['Value'])
```

Comment: Hard coding [1] is not definitively the answer. How do you know the op always wants the second element? You may as well just do `return `Model Name'`

Comment: Then you either ask questions to confirm, or you state your assumptions in your answer. But you certainly don't answer with hidden assumptions.

Comment: @radhadman Thank you for your response! It worked perfectly.
I did do some more research and leaned I was dealing with nested arrays within the object.
I also found a neat little function that helped also but it adds a module that really wouldn't be needed as long as the accepted answer is used.
https://hackersandslackers[dot]com/extract-data-from-complex-json-python/
I will also try to make my questions clearer in the future! 
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: great. As MatBailie said, a structural change in the JSON file could cause my solution to break, in which case you will want to get the value in a way that prevents future breaks. I figured that if I gave you a start on how to retrieve the value you could figure out the rest on your own. Glad I could help. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find value of dictionary with key `'Name'` and value `'Item'` you can do:

```py
import json

with open('your_data.json', 'r') as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

model_name = next((i['Value'] for lst in data['Items'] for i in lst if i['Name'] == 'Item'), 'Model name not found.')
print(model_name)
```

Prints:

```
Model Name
```

---

Note: if the dictionary is not found string `'Model name not found.'` is returned